# Phrasing for one current fellowship and one previous fellowship

Tags: funding, writing-style

I'm receiving support from Fellowship X, and previously I received support from Fellowship Y. I want to write on my website

> I am fortunate to be supported by Fellowship X. Previously, I was supported by Fellowship Y.

But it might seem that I'm not grateful for Y. If I write

> I am fortunate to be supported by Fellowship X and Y.

it is not accurate, because I'm no longer supported by Y. Is there an elegant way to phrase this?

Comment: "I am grateful that I was supported by Fellowship Y from date-1 to date-2. Currently, I am fortunate to be supported by Fellowship X."

Comment: "I am fortunate to have received support from Fellowship Y (startdate - enddate) and Fellowship X (startdate - present)."

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wax about how grateful you are if you're just providing information---note that that can also come across as bragging.

Just keep it simple and to the facts:

> I am currently supported by X (20XX-present), and was also previously supported by Y (20YY-20ZZ).